# add negative numbers up when 2 or more successive values are negative

Tags: google-sheets

Let's say you have a row containing positive or negative numbers.

Does anyone know how I can do a calculation with these numbers for when this row contains 2 or more successive negative values?

Comment: What kind of calculation? Do you just want to find if there are two consecutive negative values, or do you want to find what they are (and if so, one or every occurrence)?

Comment: Will there be multiple rows?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what calculation you want, but this could be a place to start. I looks for any consecutive negative values in any row and if it finds them it totals all the negative values in the row and puts the total at the end of the row.

```
function contiguousnegatives() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet6");//change to sheet name needed
var lr = s.getLastRow()
var lc=s.getLastColumn()
for(var i=0;i<lr-1;i++){
    var r = s.getRange(2, 1, lr-1, lc).getValues()//assumes a header row exists
count =0
totalneg=0
for(var j=0;j<lc;j++){
    if(r[i][j]<0 && r[i][j+1]<0) //if two consecutive values are negative
      {  count=count+1
      }
      if(r[i][j]<0){
        var totalneg = totalneg+r[i][j] //totals all neg values in row
     }}
if(count >0)
       s.getRange(i+2, lc+2).setValue(totalneg)// set total of neg two col  from end of row
}}
```